# Git clone with username password authentication in one go

Tags: git, bash, ssh

My current command is

```
git clone ssh://username@onboard.com/srv/git/repo
```

after that

```
password
```

... fine, works good.

Now I would like do this in one line. Something like that:

```
git clone ssh://username:password@onboard.com/srv/git/repo
```

but it`s not working and gives me the message:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

How can I clone in a single line?

Comment: did you tried using http

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to use the `http` url instead to clone it:

```
git clone http://username:password@onboard.com/srv/git/repo.git
```

***Edit***:

If in case you can do this by normal ssh only with username-password credentials, try using `sshpass` like:

```
sshpass -p password git clone ssh://username@onboard.com/srv/git/repo
```

You might have to install `sshpass` for this.

Note that this is the case when the ssh keys are not correctly configured; if the ssh keys were configured, your public key would be shared with the target server and you wouldn't have needed to enter the password (you might have had to enter a passphrase though).

Comment: "not valid: is this a git repository?" I have to do this using ssh.

Comment: are you accessing this by sshkeys, or by normal username-password based ssh authentication? If it is the first, it will be possible without the password, but otherwise you can try using sshpass (Though I'm not sure of the exact command). Try  something like `sshpass -p password git clone ssh://username@onboard.com/srv/git/repo`

Comment: Requires installing sshpass packet. It`s not a problem.

Comment: Be aware, that special characters in HTTP,  username or password need to be encoded. Use this tool to encode those http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: @mu無 After clone with `git clone http://username:password@onboard.com/srv/git/repo.git`, how can I push it to the remote repository with my username, password?

Comment: when using sshpass you might need to also use the `-P "Enter passphrase for key '/home/whatever_user/.ssh/id_rsa':"` . It works for cloning with SSH and also pull and push. Great ;)