# Clone username, password for ssh based URL

Tags: git

I wish to clone the Git repo using ssh URL using shell script as a part of automation.

So need to pass the username and password in the clone command.

How to pass the username and password in the same line.

For HTTP/HTTPS based URL I have passed the username, password in the clone command in the script, it works fine.
But for ssh based URL it is not.

General SSH based clone command which I'm using:

`git clone ssh://{user}@{host}:{port}/{repo}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git clone with username password authentication in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728428/git-clone-with-username-password-authentication-in-one-go)

Comment: You better use public keys authentication.

Answer (score 2):

```
sshpass -p password git clone ssh://{user}@{host}:{port}/{repo}
```